# Why .NET Core DI prefers constructor accepting IEnumerable<T> over parameterless one?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ienumerable

I have a simple service interface:

```cs
public interface ICustomService
{
    bool ConstructedWithNoParameters { get; }
}
```

with equally simple implementation:

```cs
public class CustomService : ICustomService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<int> _items;

    public CustomService()
    {
        _items = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

        ConstructedWithNoParameters = true;
    }

    public CustomService(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        _items = items ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
    }

    public bool ConstructedWithNoParameters { get; }
}
```

Note that based on which constructor is called, the `ConstructedWithNoParameters` is set to `true`.

Here is a simple test scenario to test it out:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    // Assert
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    // Act
    var customService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomService<int>>();

    // Arrange
    customService.ConstructedWithNoParameters.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

As I did not specify how the implementation should be constructed I would expect that parameterless constructor is called to initialize a new instance of `CustomService`. But that is not what happens. The test method above fails at ending assertion with `ConstructedWithNoParameters` being `false`. It seems to me that DI resolver prefers the other constructor accepting `IEnumerable<int>` over the parameterless one. If I leave only parameterless constructor available, the test passes.

I'm using .NET Core 2.2 and XUnit 2.4.0 for testing.

#### Question

Why DI resolver prefers constructor accepting `IEnumerable<T>` over the parameterless?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6331 may be worth a read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DI is designed to be greedy, and choose the constructor with the most parameters it can fill. An enumerable parameter can still be constructed by the DI **with an empty array**, and thus the DI still can go for that overload. I believe that is what happening under the hood.